Would an Hypothetical Ringworld Positioned Inside the Moon's Orbit Around Earth, gravitationally affect Earth?
If a ringworld were to encircle Earth within the orbit of the Moon, would it induce any gravitational alterations on Earth?
I grasp that inside a circular structure, there might not emerge a discernible gravitational force, yet I ignore if that's just a first order effect, and there are higher order effects.
Furthermore, it's plausible that the ringworld would engage in gravitational interactions with the Moon, potentially via tidal forces, consequently exerting an indirect influence on Earth, via the Moon.
Moreover, I acknowledge the prospect that the ringworld itself might lack orbital stability due to its net force being zero. In such a scenario, it could wander, potentially leading to collisions with Earth. Hence, I hypothesize that its center of rotation might be artificially stabilized, but I wonder if other disruptive factors remain unaccounted for.

If you put a massive ring around Earth, it would have some effect. A shell, by Newton's shell theorem, would have zero effect. But a ring would induce a varying gravitational potential. In the equatorial plane it would scale as $\Phi(r) = -\frac{GM}{a} [1 - (1/4)(r/a)^2 + (9/64)(r/a)^4 + \ldots]$ where $a$ is the ring radius. Above the plane the potential is weaker and hence there will be a bit of flattening if the ring mass $M$ is large (or r smallish compared to Earth's radius). If the ring is not along the rotation axis there will be a tidal torque. Similarly the moon will feel a non-uniform field that no doubt causes some precession.
Conversely, the ring will also be subject to tidal distortion from the Moon. Given that rings are not very stable against perturbations unless they are implausibly rigid, this might destabilize the whole setup.
